# conflicting types for function returning a char array

Tags: c

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char input_buffer[1000];


void get_substring(){


    int i;
    int length;

    printf("Please enter a string:\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", input_buffer);



    printf("Index of first character of substring:\n");
    scanf("%d", &i);

    printf("Length of substring:\n");
    scanf("%d", &length);

    printf("Substring is  %.*s ", length, input_buffer + i);

}


int main(void) {
    // your code goes here

    //get_substring(0,4);
    get_substring();

    return 0;
}
```

That's my current code, I want to return a pointer of the input, instead of just displaying the substring. Sorry for the confusion everyone.

Comment: What is `test`? Another variable? You need quotes if it is supposed to be a string.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you just want to return string then what is `string` doing in `get_substring()` ? What is `test`?

Comment: There's no such thing as `main` **class**, by the way.

Comment: Your function doesn't return a char array but a pointer to a `char` or an array of `char`. You have to define the pointer target. Be careful that you return a pointer to an instance that is alive after the return.

Comment: why you are catching integers in pointer value ?

Comment: What is the actual error message? And since you are trying to so something so basic it should be easy for you to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: so I have to create a pointer to the char string?

Comment: it is done as `char *myString = "String"

Comment: I'm not sure you have made your question any clearer. You've updated the code and now it's significantly different to the original snippet - the `get_substring` function no longer returns anything so the question title no longer matches the code. And this version of the code compiles fine without any error. So what exactly are you asking?

Comment: Well, since `input_buffer` is global you could just return the array index instead. To return the substring you need to 1. Allocate some memory and copy the sub-string into that new bufffer or NULL terminate the `input_buffer` at the end of the sub-string. Then 2. Return the new buffer variable or return `&input[i]`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* getSubstring(char* str,size_t start, size_t length)
{
  // determine that we are not out of bounds
  if(start + length > strlen(str))
    return NULL;

 // reserve enough space for the substring
 char *subString = malloc(sizeof(char) * length);
 // copy data from source string to the destination by incremting the 
 // position as much as start is giving us
 strncpy(subString, str + start, length);
 // return the string
 return subString;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  char *str = "Hallo Welt!";
  char *subStr = getSubstring(str,0,20);
  if(subStr != NULL)
  {
    printf("%s\n",subStr);
    free(subStr);
  }

}
```

This solution should give you a hint how you would start with such a problem.